# How to replace backslash with two blackslashes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, special-characters, backslash

I have a string in following format.

```
var myStrg = "domain\john";
```

I need to replace `\` with two `\\` characters as `domain\\john`.

How can I achieve this?

I already went through many similar questions and answers but none of them had a answer for this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT 01:

To make this question clear, I'm adding more background information here with my code. As you can see the `username` is a parameter. Its format will be something like `'domain_name\user_name'`. So when I append this `username` to the URL the problem occurs. And I don't have control over the receiving value as the username.

```
function myFunction(username) {
var fullurl = "http://myserver/mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyTestList')/items?$select=ID&$filter=Username eq '" + username + "'";

NWF$.ajax({
    url: fullurl,
    method: "GET",
    async: false,
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        //process returned data here
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('Error occurred.');
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

As per the escape sequence, `\\` represents single `\(backslash)`

```js
console.log("domain\\\\john");
```

If you are asking to replace single backslash with double,

```js
console.log("domain\\john".replace(/\\/g, '\\\\'));
```

Comment: @Downvoter, Your _comment_ is precious for me!

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that using this declaration

```
var myStrg = "domain\john";
```

Javascript will store "domainjohn", because "\j" is considered as "j". To store it with the "\" use this:

```
var myStrg = "domain\\john";
```

And if you want the double "\" use this:

```
var myStrg = "domain\\\\john";
```

And if you want to replace the single "\" programmatically using regexs, use this:

```
var myStrg = "domain\\john";
myStrg.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\")
```

**EDIT 01 RESPONSE**

After your edit, I think that maybe what you're looking for is this:

```
encodeURIComponent(username)
```

This will transform `"domain\\john"` into `"domain%5Cjohn"`, which is an accepted format for url parameters.

But again, the way to call your function is with the `"\\"`

```
myFunction("domain\\john");
```

Comment: In my code I actually receive this myStrg as a return value. So I don't know what the value will be. So I can't add double backslashes to it. But it'll be with the format like 'domain_name\username'. How should I handle this situation?

Comment: Then just use the last example: myStrg.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\")

Comment: It returns the string 'domainjohn'

Comment: May be because the original string is identified as 'domainjohn' as you mentioned above. I added the entire code block in the original question.

Comment: I changed the answer after your edit, please tell me if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

---

You can use regex in the [replace method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). The code below is not tested, but the [regex should work](http://regexr.com/3dnpr).

```
var myStrg = "domain\john";
myStrg = myStrg.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');
```

---

Comment: you have an extra parenthesis here